# Ветки удаленного репозитория

Tags: git, git-branch

Как получить список веток удаленного репозитория, не создавая локального?

Answer (score 5):

например, с помощью команды `ls-remote`:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/golang/go

a91c2e0d2d19565da38a58bf706aec79065cefc9    refs/heads/dev.cc
81b74bf9c53026aa6001c1cb622c2860d58c662f    refs/heads/dev.garbage
7904e951d4efd3dd82afcebf5856eeb78217d86d    refs/heads/dev.power64
41a7dca2722b7defafb05b0919fb8dde38819efb    refs/heads/dev.ssa
5a9d5c37479231336efef0e0fa5b75645aa1c569    refs/heads/master
08b97d4061dd75ceec1d44e4335183cd791c9306    refs/heads/release-branch.go1
1d6d8fca241bb611af51e265c1b5a2e9ae904702    refs/heads/release-branch.go1.1
43d00b0942c1c6f43993ac71e1eea48e62e22b8d    refs/heads/release-branch.go1.2
3dbc53ae6ad4e3b93f31d35d98b38f6dda25f4ee    refs/heads/release-branch.go1.3
f8c06b1f70334203f4fee20557b4b9ca7a1d9d8d    refs/heads/release-branch.go1.4
a1ef950a15517bca223d079a6cf65948c3db9694    refs/heads/release-branch.go1.5
57e459e02b4b01567f92542f92cd9afde209e193    refs/heads/release-branch.go1.6
7998d012b9823d6938dbaac929a839776b093fe4    refs/heads/release-branch.r57
0584eb2e7779d5bf699702d06acb686cd08bddd2    refs/heads/release-branch.r58
5d9765785dff74784bbdad43f7847b6825509032    refs/heads/release-branch.r59
394b383a1ee0ac3fec5e453a7dbe590d3ce6d6b0    refs/heads/release-branch.r60
```

документация: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html

Comment: А почему выбран Go? Изучаете его сейчас?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, просто под руку попался: зашёл за ссылкуой на github.com → explore → programming languages → «яблоко» пропустил, второй пункт — golang/go

Answer (score 0):

достаточно простого:

```
git branch -r
```

выводит удаленный репозиторий/ветка... и так весь список