# Как скопировать ветку в репозиторий?

Tags: git

У меня есть 1 репозиторий и внутри 3 ветки A B C.
Также я создал пустой новый репозиторий.

Как мне взять ветку B и добавить ее как основной репозиторий?

Или как мне скопировать ветку B, как обычный проект, на компьютер без всяких остальных веток и т.д.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как мне скопировать ветку B как обычный проект, на компьютер. Без всяких остальных веток

склонировать только одну (`--single-branch`) ветку `имя-ветки` из хранилища (репозитория) `url-хранилища` в `каталог-куда-клонировать`:

```
$ git clone --single-branch -b имя-ветки url-хранилища каталог-куда-клонировать
```

Comment: ` Remote branch FixAndroidMenuDesign not found in upstream origin` Вот что выдает

Comment: проверьте существование: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541621/178576