# Как клонировать только нужный коммит сабмодуля?

Tags: git

Хочу использовать определённый коммит сабмодуля как зависимость. Если просто написать `git submodule update --init --recursive`, то происходит (насколько я понимаю) клонирование всего репозитория и обычный чекаут на коммит из `.gitmodules`. Но если указать `git submodule update --init --recursive --depth=1`, то клонирование проходит гораздо быстрее, но дальше как будто ещё докачивается нужный коммит (в выводе есть *Receiving objects*) и происходит чекаут.

Правда ли, что опция `--depth=1` клонирует последний + нужный коммит? Но как тогда гит без истории определяет нужный коммит? Если да, то можно ли клонировать только 1 нужный коммит без последнего? Если это так, то почему бы всегда не использовать эту опцию, если не нужна история репозитория?

Comment: `дальше как будто ещё докачивается нужный коммит (в выводе есть Receiving objects) и происходит чекаут` объекты — это и есть то, из чего создаётся «working directory». так что можете расслабиться — скачивается только один коммит. и только те объекты, на которые он ссылается, чтобы можно было создать «working directory».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin но как без истории коммитов гит понимает, как клонировать только 1 нужный коммит? Исходя из доков, `--depth=1` делает shallow clone глубины 1, т.е. получает только последний коммит в репозитории. Как после этого мы можем сделать чекаут на рандомный коммит, если у нас нет истории? Если мы так можем сделать, то почему `--depth=1` не дефолтная опция тогда?

Comment: `получает только последний коммит в репозитории` — не последний, а тот, который вы указали. вы же указали коммит при подключении под-модуля (пусть и неявно). вот он и будет получен. а хэш нужного коммита можно узнать, совершенно ничего и не сохраняя, простым запросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541635/178576

Comment: `Как после этого мы можем сделать чекаут на рандомный коммит, если у нас нет истории?` — мы в любой момент можем сделать fetch нужного коммита, при необходимости — с указанной глубиной. ну а потом просто распаковать полученные объекты в рабочий каталог.